# how can i find caller from specific line in trace mode in delphi?

Tags: delphi, ide, breakpoints

happy new solar year.

in delphi IDE, we can put a breakpoint on specific line,
then when run in debug mode, program stops on that.
consider a method called by another. how we can find who calls method that we are in it by breakpoint?
i reallize it is possible by hitting Ctrl+Alt+C and in assembly mode track back..
is there any easier way to find out?

thanks alot.

Comment: I#ve to guess how it's may be called in english "Debug Window / CallStack" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Call Stack` window. Use `View->Debug Windows->Call Stack` from the main menu, or press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+S</kbd>

[image: Call Stack Window (Docked)]